# Javascript array values cannot resequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist

I've an array which the values are : **[1,"",2,"",3,4,5,6,7]** (size : 9)

and I try to update "" (empty string) `at index 1`  with the sequence number which my expected array like this : **[1,2,3,"",4,5,6,7,8]** (size : 9)

I've try to update the vals like this

```
   var update =  updateOtherVals(arr.slice(index));
   Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr, [index+1, update.length].concat(update));

function updateOtherVals(arr){
        arr.shift();

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if (arr[i] != "") 
            {
                arr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

here is my attempt at fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vo0yt6eL/1/ that already implemented on my apps (actually if user selected "istirahat" at specify row, the number at the row is empty but next row (column `jam ke`) filled with sequence number), I was stuck for 2 days

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: Far better to post code as a runnable snippet here, rather than a few lines with syntax errors extracted from 200 lines elsewhere. You need to show how the function is called, sample input, expected output and actual output plus any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```js
function getValues(length, emptyIndex) {
  const values = [];

  for(let i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
    const value = i === emptyIndex ? "" : i;
    values.push(value);    
  }

  return values;
}

// In on change
if ($(this).val() == "istirahat")  {
  arr = getValues(index);
}
```